# Qual maneira correcta eliminar elemento de um vector? C++

Tags: c++, vector

A maneira poderá ser a mesma para apagar um vector de inteiros, ou um vector de objectos? 
Sempre que é eliminado um elemento, terá que se mudar a posição do vector ?
A situação é a mesma eliminando no inicio ou no fim ?

Como exemplo:

vector do tipo int que contem : 2 54 6 7 8

O objectivo no meu problema seria eliminar através do indice, caso índice fosse 0, iria ser eliminado o numero 2, e o vector ficaria com: 54 6 7 8

Comment: O que você está fazendo? Dê alguma contexto, mostre onde está seu problema.

Comment: já editei o post para ser mais claro.

Comment: myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+indice);

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound o vector muda automaticamente de tamanho depois dessa instrução ? visto que se e eliminado um elemento o seu tamanho nao ira ficar o mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro lembre de dar um include

```
#include <vector>
```

2- crie o seu vector

```
std::vector <int> nomeDoVector;
```

(respondendo a primeira pergunta, vc pode criar vector de outras coisas é só mudar o campo "int", e funciona da mesma maneira)

3- Para apagar um elemento pelo indice use:

```
nomeDoVector.erase (nomeDoVector.begin()+ 2); //apaga o 3º elemento
```

ou passe uma variavel, nesse caso int i = 5;

```
nomeDoVector.erase (nomeDoVector.begin()+ i); //i = 5 apaga o 6º elemento
```

(respondendo a segunda pergunta, o vector se ajusta sozinho )

ex:
[0,2,5,1,3] -> nomeDoVector.erase (nomeDoVector.begin()+ 2)

resultado:
[0,2,1,3] -> veja que agora o numero "1" é o 3º.

A situação é a mesma eliminando no inicio ou no fim ?

Sim, voce pode usar o erase para apagar qualquer elemento, inclusive o primeiro e o ultimo. Mas se quiser voce pode usar para facilitar o

```
nomeDoVector.pop_back();
```

ele acha automaticamente quem é o ultimo e deleta.

OBS1: voce também pode apagar varios elementos de um vez só
assim:

```
nomeDoVector.erase(nomeDoVector.begin(),nomeDoVector.begin()+3);//apaga os elementos das posições 0,1 e 2.
```